# Space leak in Pipes with RWST

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

A memory analysis of the following program shows that the noleak functions runs in constant memory while the leak function leaks memory in a linear fashion. dflemstr indicated that this might be due to RWST causing an infinite chain of allocations. Is this the case and what other solutions exists? I actually dont need the Writer monad.

Environment:

GHC 7.8.3 on ARCH 64 bit

ghc Pipe.hs -o Pipe -prof

```
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
import Control.Monad (forever)

import Pipes
import Control.Monad.Trans.RWS.Strict

main = leak

effectLeak :: Effect (RWST () () () IO) ()
effectLeak =
  (forever $ do
      liftIO . threadDelay $ 10000 * 1
      yield "Space") >->
  (forever $ do
      text <- await
      yield $ text ++ (" leak" :: String)) >->
  (forever $ do
      text <- await
      liftIO . print $ text
  )

effectNoleak :: Effect IO ()
effectNoleak =
  (forever $ do
      lift . threadDelay $ 10000 * 1
      yield "Space") >->
  (forever $ do
      text <- await
      yield $ text ++ (" leak" :: String)) >->
  (forever $ do
      text <- await
      lift . print $ text
  )

leak = (\e -> runRWST e () ()) . runEffect $ effectLeak

noleak = runEffect $ effectNoleak
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce this behaviour on Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit), using GHC 7.6.3, pipes 4.1.2 and transformers 0.3.0.0. Both `noleak` and `leak` run in constant memory. Unless you compiled without optimization. So your solution is probably "use `-O2`".

Comment: I notice that the space leak disappears with -O2. However, when I turn on optimizations on a larger program using some TH-generated RWST Pipes then the space leak is still existent. Is there any other solution to get state and reader-like behaviour in the base monad?

Comment: Looking at the generated heap and stack profile reveals that the ARR_WORDS (ByteString) only grows to about 2 MB but the types (->>*) and (*) together with the stack keeps growing seemingly forever. The IO version uses less than 1 MB of memory while I've let the RWST run until around 32 MB before killing it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like the [`Writer` part of `RWST`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-RWS-Strict.html#line-167) is actually the culprit:

```
instance (Monoid w, Monad m) => Monad (RWST r w s m) where
    return a = RWST $ \ _ s -> return (a, s, mempty)
    m >>= k  = RWST $ \ r s -> do
        (a, s', w)  <- runRWST m r s
        (b, s'',w') <- runRWST (k a) r s'
        return (b, s'', w `mappend` w') -- mappend
    fail msg = RWST $ \ _ _ -> fail msg
```

As you can see, the writer uses a plain `mappend`. Since `(,,)` isn't strict in its arguments, `` w `mappend` w' `` builds a series of thunks, even tough the `Monoid` instance of `()` [is rather trivial](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Data-Monoid.html#instance%20Monoid%20%28%29):

```
instance Monoid () where
        -- Should it be strict?
        mempty        = ()
        _ `mappend` _ = ()
        mconcat _     = ()
```

In order to fix this, you need to add strictness to `` w `mappend` w' `` in the tuple:

```
        let wt = w `mappend` w'
        wt `seq` return (b, s'', wt)
```

However, if you don't need the `Writer` anyway, you can simply use `ReaderT r (StateT st m)` instead:

```
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Strict

type RST r st m = ReaderT r (StateT st m)

runRST :: Monad m => RST r st m a -> r -> st -> m (a,st)
runRST rst r st = flip runStateT st . flip runReaderT r $ rst
```

However, given that this will force you to `lift` the computations to the correct monad, you might want to use the [`mtl` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) instead. The code will stay the same, but the imports will be the following in this case

```
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.State.Strict
```

Answer (score 14):

Zeta is right, and the space leak is because of `WriterT`.  `WriterT` and `RWST` (both the "strict" and lazy versions) always leak space no matter what monoid you use.

I wrote up a longer explanation of this [here](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2013-March/019528.html), but here is the summary: the only way to not leak space is to simulate `WriterT` using a `StateT` monad where `tell` is simulated using a strict `put`, like this:

```
newtype WriterT w m a = WriterT { unWriterT :: w -> m (a, w) }

instance (Monad m, Monoid w) => Monad (WriterT w m) where
    return a = WriterT $ \w -> return (a, w)
    m >>= f  = WriterT $ \w -> do
        (a, w') <- unWriterT m w
        unWriterT (f a) w'

runWriterT :: (Monoid w) => WriterT w m a -> m (a, w)
runWriterT m = unWriterT m mempty

tell :: (Monad m, Monoid w) => w -> WriterT w m ()
tell w = WriterT $ \w' ->
    let wt = w `mappend` w'
     in wt `seq` return ((), wt)
```

That's basically equivalent to:

```
type WriterT = StateT

runWriterT m = runStateT m mempty

tell w = do
    w' <- get
    put $! mappend w w'
```

Comment: Great solution for anyone needing WriterT!

Comment: I thought I had made it clear that it's not about `mappend w w'`, but `(,,)`, sorry. An alternative version of `RWST` with `let wt = mappend w w' in seq wt $ return (b, s'', wt)` would fix this too.

Comment: @Zeta Oops, sorry.  I missed that.  I'll fix my response.