# A Stricter Control.Monad.Trans.Writer.Strict

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, monad-transformers, strictness

So we have:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer.Strict

type M a = Writer (Map Key Val) a
```

for some `Key` and `Val`.

Everything works okay as long as we don't look at the collected outputs:

```
report comp = do
  let (a,w) = runWriter comp
  putStrLn a
```

However if we want to examine `w`, we get stack overflows.

```
 report comp = do
   let (a,w) = runWriter comp
   guard (not $ null w) $ do -- forcing w causes a stack overflow
     reportOutputs w
   putStrLn a
```

The reason, I think, is because `(>>=)` for `Writer` [is defined as](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Strict.html#line-153):

```
m >>= k  = WriterT $ do
    (a, w)  <- runWriterT m
    (b, w') <- runWriterT (k a)
    return (b, w `mappend` w')
```

If I have a large `Writer a` computation, it builds up a long sequence of mappends: `w <> (w' <> (w'' <> ...))` and in this case that's a `Map.union` which is strict in the spine of the map.  So if I build up a big sequence of unions, the whole thing has to be evaluated as soon as I force the Map which overflows the stack.

What we want is to perform the unions early.  We want a stricter Strict.Writer:

```
m >>= k = WriterT $ do
    (a, w) <- runWriterT m
    (b, w') <- runWriterT (k a)
    let w'' = w `mappend` w'
    w'' `seq` return (b, w'')
```

So my question is:  does this exist in some "standard" library?  If not, why not?

Comment: That was already encountered in [Space leak in Pipes with RWST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280852/space-leak-in-pipes-with-rwst), however I don't have an answer for the "standard library" issue. The "why not" could be too opinionated.

Comment: Well "why not" was mostly anticipating responses like  "it's not in a library because you broke the monad laws when you made it too strict" or some similar technical reason.  Not something like "because [opinion]".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The immediate answer to your question is: no, there is no standard library that provides this.  Also, the version you proposed will still leak.  The only version I know that does not leak is to simulate `WriterT` using a strict `StateT`.  I wrote up a very detailed [e-mail about this to the Haskell libraries mailing list](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2013-March/019528.html) comparing the strictness and performance of several implementations.  Long story short: implementing `WriterT` as a strict `StateT` not only eliminates space leaks, but also generates very efficient code.

Here is the implementation that worked:

```
newtype WriterT w m a = WriterT { unWriterT :: w -> m (a, w) }

instance (Monad m, Monoid w) => Monad (WriterT w m) where
    return a = WriterT $ \w -> return (a, w)
    m >>= f  = WriterT $ \w -> do
        (a, w') <- unWriterT m w
        unWriterT (f a) w'

runWriterT :: (Monoid w) => WriterT w m a -> m (a, w)
runWriterT m = unWriterT m mempty

tell :: (Monad m, Monoid w) => w -> WriterT w m ()
tell w = WriterT $ \w' ->
    let wt = w `mappend` w'
     in wt `seq` return ((), w `mappend` w')
```

I would like to see this added to `transformers` at some point, but there are some minor issues that need to be resolved (i.e. what the module name should be, for one).

Comment: Is this available as a library now?

Comment: @user3237465 There is [*writer-cps-mtl*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/writer-cps-mtl-0.1.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-CPS.html) (or [*writer-cps-full*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/writer-cps-full), if you want a few extra *lens* and *mmorph* instances for it).